# Inserting text in vim causes each line to be shifted right

Tags: linux, vim

When I copy some text from one opened window (browser and text editor) to vim by pressing Shift + Insert, The text is inserted in a way that each consecutive line is shifted right with progressive amount of tabs. Meaning that second line is shifted by 1 tab, 3rd line is shifted by 2 tabs, 4th line is shifted by 3 tabs, etc. How to prevent this weird insertion and have text look in vim the same way as in the source window?

```
while True:
        reads = [p.stdout.fileno(), p.stderr.fileno()]
            ret = select.select(reads, [], [])

                for fd in ret[0]:
                            if fd == p.stdout.fileno():
                                            read = p.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: Add `set pastetoggle=<F2>` to your .vimrc to use `<F2>` to toggle paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before you paste anything, try using

```
:set paste
```

For completeness purposes, when you are done, you can go back to previous/default mode with:

```
:set nopaste
```

otherwise things like autoindent would not work. (Thanks to  Anurag Peshne for pointing this out.)

Comment: It helped! Thanks, I wish I could upvote your answer, but my rating is not high enough.

Comment: @user3610796: an addendum: use `:set nopaste` after pasting to return to normal mode else stuff like auto indenting won't work.

Answer (score 3):

> :set paste

will disable auto-indent in vim. After paste, use `:set nopaste` to re-enable your auto indent feature in vim

But if you found it annoying to toggle between `paste` and `nopaste`, just simply use the `+` register to paste:

> "+p

This will ignore any paste options in vim, just paste as-it.

more info on system clipboard register: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard